# TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD Android No data

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have written some simple code for the Galaxy Tab 7 to show the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD data. 
Unfortunately this does not provide any data.

I can see a TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD sensor (have checked it exists). I can successfully add a an event listener to it, however I never get any data from it. Other sensors work fine such as light and accelerometer. This is on a Galaxy Tab 7.

`onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is never fired for  a  `case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:`

As such I get no data from the Magnetic Field Sensor.

Anyone else getting this problem or know of a solution to it ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: not a very useful question without any code posted.  please show us what you did!

Comment: I have the same problem with SonyEricson Xperia. However compass app on the phone is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Sensor was broken. =((

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. In my case a magnetic sensor didn't work. I made sure in it after installing some compass applications and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.atools.